RPi bootlooping after apt full-upgrade
I've tried to execute sudo apt full-upgrade for my Raspberry Pi 4b and ran into an issue,
The update stopped at 60%, and since then, I haven't been able to boot it properly. I've tried to reinstall it with another SD card and even use an SD card with EEPROM flashed on it, but I still can't resolve the issue.
Each time I try to boot the OS (Raspbian-64), I see the same rainbow screen. Then, I see the beginning of my OS boot, but after 3 seconds, it crashes and begins all over again.

There seem to be two issues: the 60% update and then the rainbow screen. You say that you've reinstalled and/or used a new SD card - do they suffer the 60% issue as well (your question isn't very clear)? An incomplete update is highly likely to cause issues.

Not that it helps much, but: The rainbow screen is totally normal and always occurs, it's part of the firmware, although it usually is there so briefly it is easily unnoticed.

You can't have Raspbian-64 because there never has been one. What happens if you try without a SD Card?

It enters the boot loader as it should @Milliways

I cant boot the raspberry so I can't check if it stuck at the same point :( @Greenonline

Have you tried booting using a USB thumb drive?
